# Pass data to same component from constructor

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm fetching json file from assets folder. 
My file name is `testjson.json`.

I have used the following code to fetch json file from folder.

```
  constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/testjson.json')
                 .subscribe(data => {
                          console.log(data);
                  });
  }
```

**testjson.json** file,

```
{
   "time": "03:53:25 AM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1362196405309,
   "date": "03-02-2013"
}
```

Now,  I want to use this json data to component class (Same component class),

```
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/testjson.json')
                 .subscribe(data => {
                          console.log(data);
                  });
  }

  // I want to use data here. 

 }
```

I'm successfully getting testjson.json in `console.log(data);`

Comment: So, what is stopping you?

Comment: I'm getting data in subscribe method but not able to get data outside constructor. I'm new to typescript that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Inside the subscribe, assign `data` to a class level variable, then you can use that anywhere you need to in the component. Just *that* easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this just like create an additional variable:

```
  export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/testjson.json')
                 .subscribe(data => {
                          this.data = data;
                  });
  }

  //now you could use it where you want;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do as you are expecting. You have 2 solution to do that.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
                this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/testjson.json')
                 .subscribe(data => {
                          console.log(data);
                          // you can do whatever you want here in this block
                  });
  }



 }
```

Another way to righer callback function to do it.

```
    export class DashboardComponent implements AfterViewInit {


      constructor(private router:Router,private http:Http) {
                    this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/testjson.json')
                     .subscribe(data => {
                              console.log(data);
                              this.OnGetData(data);
                      });
      }



     }

public onGetData(data){// do your work in this method}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah I tried it but it showing me error. `Property 'onGetData' doesn't exist on type DashboardComponent.`

Comment: onGetData is function. have you create this method ?

Comment: It's working I was using `public function onGetData(data)`. that's why that error was coming.